# Help needed to figure out relationships between a few sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following sequences:

$a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]\\
b = [1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 26]\\
c = [1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13]$

I'm trying to reverse-engineer an undocumented API and believe that the values in $a$ can be used to determine the corresponding values in $b$ and $c$. For instance, we could say that third element in $b$ ($4$) is two times the value in $a$ ($2$), while the corresponding value in $c$ is the same as $a$'s. Unfortunately that algorithm doesn't work across all the values of the sequences. Does this make sense? If so, can anyone think of any common series that would give the values of $b$ and $c$`?

Comment: This is not mathematics. Maybe it is programming.

Comment: Do the sequences extend, or they have exactly 6 terms?

Comment: http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/index.html?q=1,+2,+4,+7,+13,+26

Comment: @muad I'm looking for an equation. I figured this site was more appropriate than Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is a formula for this on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: @muad: As is it's neither math nor CS but, rather, numerology.

Comment: @pr1001, it's not appropriate here (just for your information).

Comment: @pr1001: it would help if you could give more details about what the numbers are supposed to represent.  My guess is it's one of the sequences in the OEIS link and if I knew more I could tell you which one.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, the `b` and `c` sequences are dimensions of an image. Given this and the fact only `c` seems to be similar to a well-known forumla suggests that the numbers are arbitrary. Thanks for your help and for introducing me to Catalan numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't have enough information here to reverse-engineer your problem. For instance, the Generalized Catalan Numbers have been referenced in the comments (by Qiaochu Yuan) because they appear in your sequence $b.$ This sequence starts $1,1,1,2,4,7,13,26,52,104,\ldots$

However, I could define a “random” sequence by $u_1=1$ and for $n>1$
$$U_n=2U_{n-1} \quad \textrm{ for } n \equiv 0,1 \textrm{ mod } 4$$
and
$$U_n=2U_{n-1}-1 \quad \textrm{ for } n \equiv 2,3 \textrm{ mod } 4.$$

This follows the stated Catalan sequence exactly, and so contains your sequence $b,$ up until we get 103 instead of 104. I give this as an illustration that with the current information this problem has no definitive answer.

EDIT: To be fair to the question asker, I'd like to point out that the fact that he/she cannot do what he/she wants to do is often not so clear to people who've been brought up on a diet of school mathematics where one is frequently asked to fill in the missing number in a sequence or find the next number.

Comment: Trees occur fairly naturally in computer science so if I had to bet, I would actually bet that it's the generalized Catalan sequence.  But again, I'd appreciate more information.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yes, you're probably right. I'm trying to help the asker realise the dilemma here.

Comment: Thanks Derek, though excuse me if I find your comments a little harsh! My question was whether there was a common series – I didn't assume there had to be one!

Comment: @pr1001 Sorry, I didn't mean to seem harsh.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $b$ can be obtained from $a$ by the function $$t \mapsto \frac{t^4}{12}-\frac{t^3}{2}+\frac{17 t^2}{12}+1$$ and the sequence $c$ using $$t \mapsto \frac{t^5}{60}-\frac{t^4}{6}+\frac{7 t^3}{12}-\frac{t^2}{3}-\frac{t}{10}+1.$$ I am pretty sure this is not what you want!